# Deletion of a row from an association table

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy, relationship

I am working on an app using python3 and SqlAlchemy for SQLite3 database management.  I have some tables that have a Many to Many relationship.  I've created an association table to handle this relationship.

```
Class Machine(Base):
    __tablename__ 'machine'
    machine_ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    etc...
Class Options(Base):
    __tableName__ 'options'
    options_ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    etc...

The association table

Machine_Options = table('machine_options', Base.metadata,
    Column('machine_FK', Integer, ForeignKey('machine.machine_ID'),
                                 primary_key=True),
    Column('options_FK',Integer, ForeignKey('options.options_ID'),
                                 primary_key=True))
```

All the items for the Machine and Options are inserted independently.  When I want to associate a machine with an option I use an append query which works very well.

My problem is when I want to break this association between a machine and an option.  I have tried a direct row deletion from the association table using a FILTER() clause on the machine_FK and the options_FK but SqlAlchemy gives me an error informing me that 'Machine_Options' table has no field 'machine_FK'.
I have tried to remove the row from 'Machine_Options' indirectly using joins with the machine and options table but received another error that I can not delete or update using joins.

I am looking for the code to only delete a row from the association table without affecting the original machine or options table.

So far my internet search has been fruitless.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem is to use `myparent.children.remove(somechild)`

The association is made using `machine.children.append(option)`

Using the same code as the 'append' and substituting 'remove' unmakes the association

The code:

```
def removeOption(machineKey,  OptionKey):

session = connectToDatabase()

machineData = session.query(Machine).filter(Machine.machine_ID == machineKey).one()
optionData = session.query(Options).filter(Options. options_ID == OptionKey).one()
machineData.children.remove(optionData)
session.add(machineData)
session.commit()
session.close()
```

Comment: I still get raise exc.StaleDataError(
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError: DELETE statement on table 'someTable' expected to delete 1 row(s); Only 2 were matched...